# lam4-dev fails to install

Tags: apt, dpkg, mpi

Installing `lam4-dev` in a clean docker image with Ubuntu Bionic or Cosmic fails as below. Which dependency am I missing?

```
Preparing to unpack .../lam4-dev_7.1.4-3.1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lam4-dev (7.1.4-3.1build1) ...
Setting up lam4-dev (7.1.4-3.1build1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/include/lam to provide /usr/include/mpi (mpi) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.lam.1.gz (of link group mpi) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.lam.1.gz (of link group mpi) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.lam.1.gz (of link group mpi) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.lam.1.gz (of link group mpi) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/share/man/man3/MPI_Comm_set_name_lam4-dev.3.gz doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package lam4-dev (--configure):
 installed lam4-dev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lam4-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Lam4-dev package already in Ubuntu Universe Repository see https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/lam4-dev_7.1.4-3.1build1_amd64.deb.html ,try to type `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install lam4-dev`.

Comment: It could be a bug with the package assuming that a man page exists https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lam/+bug/1799434

Comment: You could do `apt-cache rdepends lam4-dev`. It will help you to understand which   dependency you missed. I guess it was openmpi or mpich.

Comment: @metallic actually `lam4-dev` conflicts with `openmpi-doc` and `mpich-doc` so they cannot be installed together.